# Email sending service in c# doesn't recover after server timeout

Tags: c#, email, .net-4.5, smtpclient

I've been having this problem for months, and it's driving me nuts.
I have a windows service written in C# (.NET 4.5) which basically sends emails, using an outlook account (I think it's an office365 service). I'm aware of the "order of credentials" problem, which isn't affecting me (many emails send correctly).

The service starts correctly and begins sending emails. Sometimes when there's too many, I get a server error to wait, the service waits a few minutes and continues perfectly on its own.

In these cases I get Error A:

```
 System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at Cobranzas.WinService.Email.SendEmail(String subject, String body, String mailTo, String attPath)
   at Cobranzas.WinService.CobranzasEmailService.SendEmails(IEnumerable`1 toSend, RepositoryEf emailRepo)
```

The problem: sometimes, and I haven't been able to find a pattern, it happens every few days, it gets a timeout error, and never recovers (**restarting the services fixes it immediately**). All subsequent sending tries fail with the same error. In this case, I get a mix of Error A and:

```
 System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Get(Object owningObject, Int32 result, Boolean& continueLoop, WaitHandle[]& waitHandles)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at Cobranzas.WinService.Email.SendEmail(String subject, String body, String mailTo, String attPath)
   at Cobranzas.WinService.CobranzasEmailService.SendEmails(IEnumerable`1 toSend, RepositoryEf emailRepo)
```

The logic of my service is as follows: I have a timer which every 5 minutes iterates over a lot of emails to be sent, and for each executes

```
Thread.Sleep(2000); 
try
{
    emailService.SendEmail(asunto, nuevoCuerpo, mail.Email, mail.AlertMessage.Attach);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is System.Net.Mail.SmtpException)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20000); // Lo hacemos esperar 20 segundos
    }
}
```

SendEmail method is:

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage();

mailMessage.To.Add(mailTo);

mailMessage.Subject = subject;
mailMessage.Body = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(body);
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(emailFromAddress, emailFromName); 
mailMessage.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");

// Attachment
if (attPath != null)
{
    var data = new Attachment(attPath, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(data);
}

var cred =
    new NetworkCredential(emailFromAddress, emailFromPassword); 

using (var mailClient =
    new SmtpClient(emailSmtpClient, emailSmtpPort) 
                     {
                         EnableSsl = true,
                         DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                         UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                         Timeout = 20000,
                         Credentials = cred
                     })
{
    mailClient.Send(mailMessage);
}

foreach (Attachment attachment in mailMessage.Attachments)
{
    attachment.Dispose();
}
```

The using SmtpClient, and attachment disposing are new, we added them trying to fix this. There was no behaviour change.
T̶h̶e̶ ̶T̶h̶r̶e̶a̶d̶.̶S̶l̶e̶e̶p̶ ̶a̶f̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶i̶m̶e̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶u̶n̶t̶e̶s̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶y̶e̶t̶.

Given that restarting the service fixes it, I'm suspecting something not being closed/cleaned appropriately, but I've checked and can't find what it could be. I found [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/146711/smtp-never-sends-the-quit-command) link a while ago, but it looks pretty old.

Any help is much appreciated!

**[PROGRESS]**

I've tested the 20" wait after a timeout and nothing, it's still failing in the same way. Any ideas? We're really stumped with this.

Comment: you have no try catch blocks to make sure that when an exception happens, to handle it (i.e log it or whatever) then let the application run as normal. So this is why your app basically crashes. The code seems fine on initial inspection so I can only suggest that it could be a problem with your mail service somewhere. Alternatively, I would check to see at what point this causes a problem and investigate the circumstances such as how many emails are being sent or what the email msg contains causing it to time out.

Comment: _have a timer which every 5'_

are those seconds? Or minutes? Also how long does it take you to restart your service? If it takes you more than 5' I'd add a `Thread.Sleep();` when a timeout occurs. Since your code seems fine it could be a server side 'problem'. (I know I would block a client that tries to authenticate via SSL every 5 seconds...)

Comment: Ahmed, I do have try catch blocks, but in the outer part, I try the emailService.SendEmail method, and log. This is how I have these exceptions logged.

Steffen, 5 minutes. Restarting is really quick, maybe 10 seconds? I forgot to clarify that I do have a few thread sleeps, one of 2 seconds before sending emails (the idea was to wait after sending one, but instead of putting it in the try and catch, I put it before. And a 20000 one after timeouts, haven't tested this last part yet.

Comment: Could you try managing the number of connections opened at a time and using same connection for several times instead of killing it for each send operation? I suspect it's something with the connection pool of smtp (that you consume all of them). And also please use this line in a try finally block mailClient.Send(mailMessage); mailClient.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup(mailClient.ServicePoint.ConnectionName);

Answer (score 11):

I have the exact same problem. I found the solution here:

System.Net.WebException when issuing more than two concurrent WebRequests
[http://www.wadewegner.com/2007/08/systemnetwebexception-when-issuing-more-than-two-concurrent-webrequests/](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815175006/https://www.wadewegner.com/2007/08/systemnetwebexception-when-issuing-more-than-two-concurrent-webrequests/)

Basically, I changed the max number of connections allowed concurrently to a single external server. By default, according to that documentation it was 2. Although, it has a timeout (it waits sometime until one is released and then continues), at sometimes, it is not enough and it hangs.

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <connectionManagement>
        <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
        </connectionManagement>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

I have not been able to find out how to recover after first timeout but hopefully this would get out "timeout" errors out of the way for some time.

Comment: I have the same problem as @shinax - an email-sending app using multiple SMTP connections starts to time out in `System.Net.ConnectionPool.Get` and when it falls into this condition, it never recovers until app restart. Bumping `maxconnection` solves the problem for me.

Comment: Will there be any impact on the application after adding this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the maximum number of connections may help, but I am not 100% sure if it won't postpone the issue until these number of connections have been reached. I decided to switch to [MailKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/) instead. It has its own SMTP client implementation that is nearly a drop-in replacement and can work with the regular `MailMessage` object (if you depend on it). It doesn't use the connection pool at all, so it might be a more safe solution.