# What is causing my ASP.NET MVC app to stop emailing and recycling the app pool to immediately fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

Every 30 to 60ish minutes, our app's email notifications (via System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient) stop sending. As soon as we recycle the app pool, the emails start flowing again. I have checked and double-checked the code and added additional USING statements to make certain all SmtpClient-related objects are being properly disposed after use. If it were an SMTP issue I don't think recycling the app pool would fix it. Has anyone else encountered this issue and figured out the root cause and fix?

Comment: Do you have idle time-out set up in your app pool (default is 20 minutes)? Any messages about your app pool in system logs?

Comment: Are the notifications in response to some activity or is it something that's scheduled to run periodically?  ASP.NET is a request/response platform, so if there are no actual requests the app may be shut down by IIS.

Comment: The notifications are in response to certain activities.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see from the previous experience with `Quartz.NET`, the  problem is most probably related to `IIS` rather than the schedulers i.e. `Quartz.NET`, `Hangfire`, etc. You might try to install [Keep Alive Service For IIS 6.0/7.5](https://keepalive.codeplex.com/) on the server to which you publish your application. After that, your published application will be alive after application pool recycling, IIS/Application restarting, etc.

***Note:*** If you use `IIS 7.5` and above you can use the last version of `Keep Alive` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution in this SO answer: [Email sending service in c# doesn't recover after server timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633809/email-sending-service-in-c-sharp-doesnt-recover-after-server-timeout)

Bump `maxconnections` in your `web.config`