# Quartz for asp.net gets killed by iis server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, quartz.net

After reading this :

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net

I was quite happy i could publish a web site that would do scheduled task on itself... Or that was i tought.

We did it, and it seems like IIS servers kill quartz just like any other scheduled task programmed inside web sites...

Am i right ?

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on **[What is causing my ASP.NET MVC app to stop emailing and recycling the app pool to immediately fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702817/what-is-causing-my-asp-net-mvc-app-to-stop-emailing-and-recycling-the-app-pool-t/36703584#36703584)**. Hope this helps...

Comment: @MuratYıldız I added value to your answer, what about me ? I gave-up quartz and used an old task scheduler instead... But your answer is useful for futur users.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do not worry :) I also marked the question as useful. Regards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

Basically - unless configured to do so, IIS will simply stop the application pool. Even if not, you put yourself into a corner for later growth.

The proper solution is to use an external scheduler (and possibly call a special URL to do the processing).

Comment: Are there any external schedulers you can recommend?